# Iptables не работает разрешение

Tags: iptables

Имеются такие правила для iptables:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я полагала, что таким образом все должно резаться, а доступ будет открыт только к одному айпишнику. Но на деле он не пингуется. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: MedGel ? пингуется он.

Comment: при таких правилах не пингуется(((

Comment: прямо сейчас какие правила?

Сейчас пинг вполне себе идет.

Comment: Занесите, пожалуйста, текст правил для iptables в текст вопроса. Изображения не очень подходят для текстовой информации.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, балда балдою... надо было iptables -A OUTPUT -d айпишник -j ACCEPT а потом дроп. Мало того, что я дроп сделала первым, так я destination с source  перепутала... нуб нубский..